# Contao CMS: Get Page Content from Page-ID in PHP-Variable

Tags: php, variables, contao

I'm using rock solid custom elements in Contao.
In the BE I have a pagetree where I can pick an internal page.
I can access the contao page id in PHP in my FE html5-document.
What I want would be to access the h1-headline of the picked page (has normal contao text element) and have it in a php-variable (in case just the whole page content is accessible, that would be ok too).

```
 $pageObj = Database::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM tl_page WHERE id = ?")
->limit(1)
->execute($pageId);
$pageArr = $pageObj->fetchAssoc();
```

With the code above I can access many variables of the picked page through the id but I don't find the headline nor the page content.

Answer (score 2):

The page does not have content itself. A page in Contao consists of so called *articles* (`tl_article`). Each article can be positioned in different *sections* of your *page layout*.

Those articles consist of so called *content elements* (`tl_content`). A content element can be a headline, text, images, etc.

In order to get the *first* content element of a page in the *main* section of the layout, you could do something like this:

```php
$objArticle = \ArticleModel::findPublishedByPidAndColumn($pageId, 'main')->first();
$objContent = \ContentModel::findPublishedByPidAndTable($objArticle->id, \ArticleModel::getTable())->first();
```

Instead of using the Contao models, you could also use a simple query:

```
$db = \Database::getInstance();
$arrContent = $db->prepare("SELECT c.* FROM tl_content AS c, tl_article AS a 
                             WHERE a.pid = ? AND c.pid = a.id AND a.inColumn = 'main' 
                             ORDER BY a.sorting, c.sorting 
                             LIMIT 1;")->execute($pageId)->fetchAssoc();
```